# What should we put in the 6th box?

Tags: visual, pattern, sequence

Below there is a small sequence. What should we put in the 6th box?

[image: sequence]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is the completed sequence:

> [image: the same image from the question, with the sixth box remaining empty]

Let's take a look at the full picture:

> [image: six music notes, increasing in length from a 32nd note on the left to a whole note on the right]

Thus, the images in the boxes represent

> the stems of the notes, which the whole note (or semibreve) does not have.

Comment: That was quick! Correct. Initially I had rotated every box by 90 degrees, but thought that would be maybe too farfetchted... and too hard.

Comment: @Lezzup: I am consistently surprised by the ingenuity demonstrated by the users of this site... I am quite ready to believe that some of them have a crystal ball.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of rot13(svobaanpv frdhrapr) :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the same as the third picture? I was thinking that 4 and 5 were where the pattern "rebounds" and doubles back on itself and the 6th is the first in the other direction. Perhaps it is even mirrored on a vertical line between 4 and 5.

Comment: Hi Lurn, welcome to Puzzling! If there are already some answers given, you could check if one of them has a green checkmark. It means that it's the correct answer. In this case, you should totally see juicifer's answer :)

Comment: I see! Did not expect that. Haha. Thank you!